# Javascript Function Stops Safari from Any Other Actions

Tags: javascript, function

I am using a Javascript function to animate counting a number up.  Whenever that function runs Safari doesn't allow any other Javascript to run on the page, including actions associated with the navigation.

Here is the code:

```
function animateCountUp(containerSpan){
  //We pull the max number from the data-number attribute on the container span.
  var maxNumber = containerSpan.attr('data-number');
  maxNumber = Number(maxNumber);

  //Add active class at start and remove at the end.  This way we don't run it again while it's already running.
  //This was required for IE7 and IE8.
  containerSpan.addClass('active');

  var currentNumber = 0;
  var i = setInterval(function(){
    if(currentNumber <= maxNumber){
      containerSpan.text(currentNumber);
      currentNumber++;

    }
    else{
      clearInterval();
      containerSpan.removeClass('active');
    }
  }, 1);
}
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: An example of what would be passed to containerSpan is:

`<span class="num" data-number="757"></span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues:

1. Is `containerSpan` a jQuery object?
2. You are never stopping the interval because you aren't passing the interval ID to `clearInterval` like `clearInterval(i)`.
3. Your interval time is set to `1ms`.  That's basically going to use max CPU and go way faster than can visually be seen.

If containerSpan is a jQuery object, I would try this:

```
function animateCountUp(containerSpan){
  //We pull the max number from the data-number attribute on the container span.
  var maxNumber = containerSpan.data('number');

  //Add active class at start and remove at the end.  This way we don't run it again while it's already running.
  //This was required for IE7 and IE8.
  containerSpan.addClass('active');

  var currentNumber = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(currentNumber <= maxNumber){
      containerSpan.text(currentNumber);
      currentNumber++;

    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      containerSpan.removeClass('active');
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

Beyond this, you need to check your error console or debug console to see what javascript errors are being reported.  That should always be the very first thing you look at when scripts aren't running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

is containerSpan a jquery object( i.e. $('nameOf the object')) because it looks like you're using jquery methods but i dont see any jquery objects for them to be used on
try right clicking and using inspect element to see if there are any errors in your console log

Comment: It will be passed jQuery object.  I posted an example of the object that would be passed in as a comment on my original post.

Thanks.

Comment: what does the call to the function animateCountUp() look like?